# How to filter out the records using sql which has the same transcation code in a table

Tags: sql-server

**Expected output(**below OrgnztnNumberID   is only an example**):**

```
OrgnztnNumber   CardStatusCode  TrnsctnTypeCode
7317704            Expired           607
7317704            Active            607
```

---

**Table data:**

```
Select OrgnztnNumber, CardStatusCode, TrnsctnTypeCode from [CSB10020_ProfileApplctn].[dbo].[CST01140_CreditCard] with(nolock)

OrgnztnNumber   CardStatusCode  TrnsctnTypeCode
2316                Expired        601
2316                Active         013
6688                Active         600
6688                Expired        604
6695                Active         013
6695                Active         607
7616760             Expired        604
7616760             Active         604
7616760             Active         013
6728                Expired        600
6728                Active         013
6731                Active         013
7317704             Expired        607
7317704             Active         607
7317704             Active         013
```

How to filter out the records which has the same transcation code in a table with same organisaton id but with different cardstatuscode(like one is "Expired" and another is "Active").

Comment: did you try group by

Comment: hi i tried, but no luck

Comment: for which coloumn i have to use group by.

Comment: What was expected output for the above data ? Use for all three columns .

Comment: And is the transaction code is going to be the same for the each organization for each status ?

Comment: i want the output like OrgnztnNumber   CardStatusCode  TrnsctnTypeCode
7317704            Expired           607
7317704            Active            607

Comment: transcation code is different for each CardStatusCode  but organization will be same

Comment: only for few records the transcation code is same even though CardStatusCode is different

Comment: Add your all scenario data with expected output to the question

Comment: @coder of code- i updated with expected output. pls check

Comment: Your expected output is not in the given table data . Please give the table data for that organization.

Comment: Added those two organisations which are having same trsnctntypecode

Comment: Use @Giorgi query with the where and you get the expected output out of the given data. If there are any more scenario of different data then update your data with them.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      OrgnztnNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      CardStatusCode NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      TrnsctnTypeCode NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '7317704', 'Expired', '607' ),
        ( '7317704', 'Active', '607' ),
        ( '7317705', 'Active', '607' ),
        ( '7317705', 'Active', '607' )


SELECT  DISTINCT t1.*
FROM    @t t1
        JOIN @t t2 ON t2.OrgnztnNumber = t1.OrgnztnNumber
                      AND t2.TrnsctnTypeCode = t1.TrnsctnTypeCode
                      AND t2.CardStatusCode <> t1.CardStatusCode
ORDER BY t1.OrgnztnNumber, t1.TrnsctnTypeCode , t1.CardStatusCode
```

Output:

```
OrgnztnNumber   CardStatusCode  TrnsctnTypeCode
7317704         Expired         607
7317704         Active          607
```

Comment: I think it also need to show the `7317705` organization.

Comment: i tried with ur code but total 9000 records are coming, actually there are only 2 records like this scenario

Comment: It's not the expected output for provided test data. Provide test data and output that you expect from that data

Comment: The above solution should work for you by your given data just needed the `Where` clause for that customer.

Comment: oh it means i have to use where organization id= " ". there is no alternate query without entering the organization id?

Comment: @rajkumar, man if you want only  '7317704 ' you should use where(I've updated answer). Other way you will get all combinations of differences.

Comment: i only used "7317704" as example , actually i want all the organization ids which have different cardstatus code but with same transactiontypecode

Comment: @rajkumar I can not understand. Doesn't 7616760 satisfy your condition? It is the same as 7317704. Why 7616760 should not come out in result, can you explain?

Comment: actually there are 3 million records , in those few records were affected by having same transactiontypecode somehow. So i have to show which records are affected by query , I gave those two IDS as example, so people will understand easily

Comment: Can you explain why 7616760 should not come out in result? From you test data it's the same as 7317704. `7616760             Expired        604`
`7616760             Active         604`. Look you have same OrgnztnNumber   and TrnsctnTypeCode but different CardStatusCode. Isn't it correct?

Comment: that expected output which i was added was dummy. I want both 7616760 , 7317704 and as well remaining million of records which are having same scenario like these two organization Ids

Comment: @rajkumar, are you kidding me man? sometimes you need only 7317704, now you need 7616760. Remove WHERE OrgnztnNumber = '7317704' and you will get what you want

Comment: huh , no . i edited the question again bcoz it was misleading you all. all are thinking that those two ids are having same TrnsctnTypeCode but its not.

Comment: there were so many other ID's also but to get all which are affected i want a query to get all at once rather than using where id = "7616760 " or "7317704" or "xxxxx" or "aaaaaa"

Comment: i never told i want only those two ID's , i told i want like those ids which are having same transctioncode

Comment: removing the where clause. i got below output:

Comment: OrgnztnNumber CardStatusCode TrnsctnTypeCode
7660675                      Expired         600
6384720                      Active                 600
7803964                     Active                 604
7626738                     Expired 604
6232111                   Cancelled  013
7595091                    Active          607
7950625                    Active         604
6411620                    Active         013
8545966                    Active         013

Comment: i did remove but no use.

Comment: @rajkumar, I think you get many rows without any ordering and you get confused. Verify updated statement where I am ordering